# How do I assign Power BI administrator role to a security group?

Tags: azure, powerbi, power-platform

I can assign a user the role of power bi admin.

I have a security group with 5 users. How do I assign Power BI administrator role to a security group? Can this be done in azure portal or tenant admin portal?

Answer (score 0):

There is a preview feature that supports this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-concept

[Screenshot from AAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJvuX.png)